# How to make user forcefully update the newer version of the app available

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have uploaded my app on iTunes but it have some errors now i need to upload newer version of the app and force user to update to that version. How can i do this .. I need help on this..Thanks in advance

Comment: This can help you out: https://github.com/emotality/ATAppUpdater

Answer (score 2):

If you already uploaded you app, this is not possible. You need to implement this yourself. Basically check against some server where you get the current version from. If the app version doesn't match this one, just show an error message.

In iTunesConnect you can specify that the old version will appear in iCloud, see this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW3

But note that this doesn't affect people who have already downloaded your app.